# Wifi required in out building same phase electricity

Tags: wireless-router, ethernet

Can anybody help please?
Ive got a good Wifi signal around my house.
I would like to get the signal into an outbuilding on the same Electricity phase.
I have 2 x Netgear 85 Mbps Wall plugged Ethernet adapters.
I also have a Netgear  AC1900 Wifi Range Extender.

Id like to know if I can plug into the mains all 3 units ..1 ethernet adapter into my Router and if I plug the other unit into my outbuilding socket and the Wifi ranger extender into the mains in there If I link those 2 pieces of kit via an ethernet cable and select access point on the Wifi Range Extender will it give me Wifi in there?

Thank you in anticipation ;)

Comment: Since you have the units would it not be easier to just try the setup?  We don’t know how your house is wired.  However, in order to work, the units have to be on the same circuit typically that isn’t done for an “outbuilding” as they typically have their own circuit

Comment: From  https://homenetworkgeek.com/do-powerline-adapters-need-to-be-on-the-same-circuit/  . Powerline adapters should work even when connected to different electrical circuits providing they meet at the same distribution board, but they will not perform as well as if they were connected to the same circuit. The quality of the electrical wiring will also influence how well they perform    So I do not think this will work well in an out building.

Comment: Here is a good article for you to review:  https://www.madebywifi.com/blog/8-tips-for-extending-wifi-range/   ..  Note in point 6 the suggestion to run Ethernet between buildings to give you the best results.

Comment: The Powerline adapter works  in as much as the outbuilding adaptergives the signal that its working.My worry is i might screw up if i connect the Wifi range extender to it via the Ethernet points.